# Android: HttpURLConnection getInputStream takes very long

Tags: android, base64, http-post, httpurlconnection

I'm uploading a 1MB long JSON string, which contains a Base64 encoded pdf file.
Here's my code:

```
fun call(url: URL, payload: String): String {

    val conn = url.openConnection()

    if (conn !is HttpURLConnection) {
        throw Exception("Invalid connection type")
    }

    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    conn.requestMethod = HttpMethod.POST.toString()
    conn.instanceFollowRedirects = false
    conn.doInput = true
    conn.setUseCaches(false)
    conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024)
    conn.doOutput = true

    val os = conn.outputStream

    Log.d(TAG, "Payload size: ${(payload.toByteArray().size / 1024 / 1024f)}")
    Log.v(TAG, "Payload: $payload")

    val writer = BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"))
    writer.write(payload)
    writer.close()
    os.close()

    val inputStream = measureExecution("conn.getInputStream()") {
       conn.getInputStream()
    }

    val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"))
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    var line: String?
    while (bufferedReader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
        sb.append(line)
    }

    bufferedReader.close()

    val response = sb.toString()

    Log.d(TAG, "response: $response")

    return response

}

inline fun <T> measureExecution(logMessage: String, function: () -> T): T {
    val startTime = System.nanoTime()
    return function.invoke().also {
        val difference = System.nanoTime() - startTime
        Logger.d(TAG, "$logMessage; took ${TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(difference)}secs")
    }
}
```

It takes approximately 40 seconds and it's all during conn.getInputStream() as I can see from the log "conn.getInputStream(); took 49ms"

Same API using Postman takes 2 seconds under the same wifi connection.

Using multipart seems an overkill to me as file size is max 1MB..

I don't think code has issues to be honest but what else could it be?

**UPDATE:** I tried with Retrofit, same thing.

Comment: Postman on the same phone?

Comment: How much time takes logging the payload?

Comment: @blackapps logging the payload takes almost 0 seconds, I just edited the question, it's conn.getInputStream() that takes time

Comment: @blackapps nope, Postman on my laptop

Comment: Try without the two close() statements.

Comment: If it is not the uploading but only getting an inputstream then change subject of your post. Do not use chunck mode.

Comment: Does it improve if you comment the statement `conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024)`

Comment: @Darkman, nope, I tried with that.. weird thing is that if I replace the URL with a free web API and post the same payload it takes 2 seconds.. but then why it takes only 2 seconds from Postman?

Comment: Tyr adding chuck interceptor and run the app it would show what sort of network issue is taking itme

Comment: @StackDiego Have you tried different devices?